# Использование скриптом серверного времени

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы мой код javascript брал время с сервера и не с устройства клиента?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 g=<?php echo date("Y"); ?>;   // тут я беру дату события 
d_n_31=new Date(g, 11,31,18, 27);    // тут я беру дату события

function on() {                                    // запускаю функцию отсчета
timeoutId = setInterval(f_d_n_31, 1000);          // запускаю функцию отсчета
clearInterval(id);                               // запускаю функцию отсчета

function f_d_n_31() {

v=d_n_31; // время события
td = new Date();   // время сейчас - берет время устройства а не с сервера

td = Math.floor((v-td)/1000) 
tsec=td%60;  td=Math.floor(td/60); 
if(tsec<10)tsec='0'+tsec;  tmin=td%60;  td=Math.floor(td/60); 
if(tmin<10)tmin='0'+tmin;  tj=td%24; td=Math.floor(td/24);
if (td>0){ tmr=td +" дней "+ tj+" чаc. "+tmin+" мин. "+tsec+" c.";}
else {if (tj>0){tmr=tj+" чаc. "+tmin+" мин. "+tsec+" c.";}
 else{if (tmin>0){tmr=tmin+" мин. "+tsec+" c.";} 
 else{if (tsec>0){tmr=tsec+" c.";}
 else{f_y_u_1()};};};};document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=tmr;window.setTimeout("f_d_n_31()",1000);};  
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 on();
</script>

 <p style="font-size:30px" align=""> До события осталось: <br/> <br/> <span id="t"  ></span> </p>
```

Comment: @Руслан904322, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
td = new Date();
```

заменить на

```
td = new Date(<?= (time() * 1000) ?>);
```

Будет текущее время сервера.

Comment: Дмитрий, огромное спасибо, вы даже не представляете, как я вам благодарен!!!!! Около недели мучался!!!!!  Также спасибо сайту!!!!!!!!!!!!